# Can Images with uniqueID be unlinked from files which are stored in to php database as BLOB?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have runned into a problem with my code. I have uploaded my images into the database as a BLOB and also moved my image as an image with a unique ID or in my scenario like this {{ img/5e0a5f121e4468.89602240.jpg }}. Now what i am trying to do  is delete the image from database and also in the same time unlink the image which has this unique ID . Here Below i have the code that submits the form in the database with the image :

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include "conn.php";

$imgOne=$_FILES['pictureOne'];

$fileName=$imgOne['name'];
$fileTmpName=$imgOne['tmp_name'];
$fileSize=$imgOne['size'];
$fileError=$imgOne['error'];

$fileExt=explode('.',$fileName);
$fileExt=strtolower(end($fileExt));

$newFileName=uniqid('',true).'.'.$fileExt;

$path='C:/xampp/htdocs/img/'.$newFileName;

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$path)){
$query="INSERT INTO images(pictureOne)
        VALUES('$newFileName')";
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
};
};
```

In the other file where i preform the deletion of the image from the databse is this :

```
include 'conn.php';
$id=$_GET['id'];

$queryD="DELETE pictureOne FROM posts WHERE id='$id'";
$resultD=mysqli_query($conn,$queryD);
```

Now please if you could help me out how would i unlink the image from my image folder since the problem for me is this unique ID which i can wrap mu head around. 
Thank you alot for the help.

Comment: What is the problem in calling `unlink()` with the file you want to delete?

Comment: Looks like you are storing the name of the file in the database, not the image itself.

Comment: After successful insert - unlink $path. This will remove file stored in db from disk.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you correctly, you are storing the file with a particular unique name and then storing that file name in the database. Later on, you want to remove the row from the database and delete the file.

First, select the row from the table so that you can get the name of the file that you originally stored. Delete the row from the database. Delete the file.

Comment: yes thats what i am tryng to do . the remove the row with the image in the database and after that i also want to unlink the image from my folder , but keep in minde that the image is moved in the image folder with a unique id that i created , So simply when i delete the image from the database i want the matched image also to be deleted from the files. You can see that in the second part of the code that ia m deliting the row.